# 10 volt ac to 10 volt dc

Tags: ac, transformer, dc, converter

I have 10 volt ac that I get from transfo that I wanna convert to 10 volt DC, 
what is the circuit to achieve that ? diode bridge, capacitors and regulator I guess ?
is it the best to use a zener diode to smooth signal or regulator ?
thank you

Comment: You can't reliably get 10VDC from 10VAC; some voltage must be sacrificed in order to have some measure of stability in the output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that would depend how much current he needs...

Comment: @Trevor_G: Absolutely. But since all we have is "10VDC" there's no way to do the math.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yup

Comment: 10VAC (RMS) will give you about 12-13V at full load which is a bit tight on 10VDC out. You really need to specify the required current, but you will need a relatively large filter cap (because ripple subtracts from the peak output voltage, as does mains dips) and an LDO or to load the transformer less to get more voltage out of it.

Comment: I will use this 10 volt DC to power on my arduino uno, not sure yet how much current it consumes

Comment: best bet: a shottkey-based bridge rectifier and normal smoothing capacitors.

Comment: You don't need 10V for an Arduino Uno; you can get away with 7V if you're providing power to the barrel connector, or 5V if you're providing it to the correct pin.

Comment: Is 10VAC measured voltage, or the transformer's rating? Does it have an Amps or VA rating?

Answer (score 1):

A diode bridge and a capacitor in between will give you a DC current. But the DC value will be 2Vd,on (the voltage across the diodes when they are on) less than the peak value of the AC voltage. I actually learned this theoretically but have not tested it in lab, so I am not sure how accurate the DC voltage will be in practice. I attached the circuit image for you. Vout is the voltage across the capacitor.  [image]